# Property of continuous and uniformly convergent seqeunce $\{f_n\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions which converges uniformly to a function $f$ on a set $E$. Prove that $$\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_n)=f(x)$$ for every sequence of points $x_n\in E$ such that $x_n\to x,$ and $x\in E$. Is the converse of this true?

**Proof:** Since $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence of continuous functions which converges uniformly to a function $f$ on a set $E$ then $f$ is continuous on a set $E$. Hence for every sequence of points $x_n\in E$ such that $x_n\to x,$ and $x\in E$ we have $f(x_n)\to f(x).$

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given then $\exists N_1=N_1(\epsilon)$ such that for any $n\geq N_1$ we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$ for any $x\in E$. Also $\exists N_2=N_2(\epsilon)$ such that for any $n\geq N_2$ we have $|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$.
Let $N_0=\max \{N_1, N_2\}$. Then $\forall n\ge N_0$ we have $|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|<\epsilon/2$ and $|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon/2$. Thus for given $\epsilon>0$ we find $N_0$ such that for any $n\ge N_0$ we get $$|f_n(x_n)-f(x)|\leqslant|f_n(x_n)-f(x_n)|+|f(x_n)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$ which is equivalent to $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_n)=f(x).$

**Is the converse of this true?** **i.e.** Let $f_n\in C(E)$ and if for every sequence $x_n\in E$ such that $x_n\to x\in E$ we have $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f_n(x_n)=f(x).$ Does it follow that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on a set $E$?

Let's $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $E=[0,1)$. It's easy to check that $\{f_n\}$ does not uniformly converges to limit function $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $E=[0,1)$. But for any sequence $p_n\in E$ such that $p_n\to p\in E$ we have that $f(p_n)=p_n^n\to 0=f(p)$ as $n\to \infty$.

Dear colleagues! What did you think about my proof and counterexample? Are they correct?

Comment: In your proof, you tacitly relied on the triangle inequality.  You might consider making this explicit.  Otherwise well done.

Comment: @Dr.MV, Edited! Thanks a lot for your checking!

Comment: @RFZ good job! you might consider posting your proof as an answer and verifying it, so that others might find it when searching for this question.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  And +1 for the question

Comment: I think you should provide more reasoning for the convergence $p_n^n \to 0$. It is not hard, but right now you do not provide any justification.